# git post-receive hook not Triggering Jenkins job (Machine-1: Local ,Machine-2: Remote)

Tags: python, git, jenkins, githooks

Facing issue while using git post-receive hook in Remote to trigger Jenkins Job. please need inputs.

**All OK condition:**
same Machine : Local and Remote
post-receive hook in Remote Triggers Jenkins job
Update in  **Git Polling Log**
Build Triggers - Poll SCM

**Problem Condition:**
Machine-1: Local , Machine-2: Remote
post-receive hook in Remote doesn't triggers Jenkins job
No update in  **Git Polling Log**
Build Triggers - Poll SCM
*if `http://machine-2:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=file://D:\GitServer.git` is executed from Machine-1 browser, post-receive hook in Remote triggers the Jenkins job in machine-2*.
**Observation :** Jenkins job in machine-2 is not triggered when git push is performed from machine-1.

**Note:** using tortoisegit in both machines.

**post-receive hook:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log = check_output([
        'curl',
        '-X',
        'POST',
        'http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=file://D:\GitServer.git'
    ])
```

Comment: Make sure your hook is truly executable, i.e., that it has the right mode (`chmod +x`), that `/usr/bin/env` exists, and that there are no other controls on your computer that disable this kind of execution. These may depend on your specific OS.

Comment: Jenkins job is triggered when I run .py file with same code as hook. Machine 2 is running on winserver 2019.

Comment: I don't think scripts work at all on Windows. See also [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/373706/how-can-i-run-a-shell-script-in-windows).